# Both horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, scroll

I'm using jquery mobile and phonegap.
Here's my problem. When I have in div vertical scrolling my horizontal scrolling of container doesn't work anymore and I have to start swiping outside that div.
Can I force to always maintain horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Use overflow-x, overflow-y